# What's an alternative for "hidden gem"?

Tags: idioms, formality, writing-style, register

*Hidden gems* is an idiom which means something which is extremely outstanding and not many people may know about; for example, *Blame It on Rio* by Stanley Donen is a good movie, but relatively unknown by the mainstream world, hence a hidden gem.

*Hidden gem* however does seem to be informal, is there an alternative phrase for this which I can use in a formal context?

It is also known as *a diamond in the rough,* which is defined as;

> someone or something whose good qualities are hidden

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is an idiom that covers everything, but you may find use in these:

**[few and far between](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Few+and+Far+Between)** (rare and difficult to find)

> very few; few and widely scattered. *Get some gasoline now. Service
>   stations on this highway are few and far between*.
>
> ***Some people think  that good movies are few and far between*.**

[**scarce**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scarce)

> 1. Insufficient to meet a demand or requirement; short in supply: *Fresh vegetables were scarce during the drought*.
> 2. Hard to find; absent or rare: *Steel pennies are scarce now except in coin shops.*

**[once in a blue moon](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/once+in+a+blue+moon)** (rare event)

> Rarely, once in a very long time, as in *We only see our daughter once
>   in a blue moon.* This term is something of a misnomer, because an
>   actual blue moon-that is, the appearance of a second full moon in the
>   same calendar month-occurs every 32 months or so. Further, the moon
>   can appear blue in color at any time, depending on weather conditions.
>   [Early 1800s]

**[hole in one](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hole+in+one)** (rare achievement)

> A perfect achievement, as in *Tim scored a hole in one on that test.*
>   The term alludes to a perfect stroke in golf, where one drives the
>   ball from the tee into the hole with a single stroke. [c. 1900]

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly this is not precisely an answer to the question as asked, but be not too hasty to reject *hidden gem* as unsuitable for formal discourse.

Formal discourse does not eschew idiom provided that the idiom in question is neither conspicuously vulgar nor excessively specific to a single region or social grouping; it aims at a certain universality. In this, the use of formal English resembles the use of Latin, rather than vernacular languages, in pre-modern Europe, for academic as opposed to literary texts (which more commonly *were* in vernacular languages): to write in Latin was to write for an international community of scholars whose vernacular mother tongues might vary from Icelandic to Portuguese to Low Dutch.

*Hidden gem* qualifies as a reasonably universal idiom, found at comparable frequencies in both [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hidden%20gem&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hidden%20gem&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) English. Its currency is likely at least partially owed to the following lines in Thomas Gray’s “Elegy Written in a Country Churchyard”:

> Full many a gem of purest ray serene
>   The dark unfathom’d caves of ocean bear:
>   Full many a flower is born to blush unseen,
>   And waste its sweetness on the desert air.

Needham Bryan Cobb in 1879 published a poetical [“Reply”](https://books.google.com/books?id=RYYUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=hidden%20gem%20gray%20elegy&source=bl&ots=QFuix_ooVH&sig=G7D23q6UNKSbFtkOAHXM9ZOSxqE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jzkhVYrqPIL7sAXXpIDIBQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=hidden%20gem%20gray%20elegy&f=false) to these lines specifically, subtitled “the unseen rose—the hidden gem.”

Answer (score 1):

Possible choice

**underappreciated** item/thing

**lucky find**

[in some contexts]

Comment: Underrated as well. :)

Comment: Not quite, it doesn't have the same "punch," something that is underappreciated could still be a Picasso. What I'm looking for is relatively unknown, but appreciated in its own merits.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of films, [cult film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_film), or cult classic are often used to describe hidden gems.

Comment: Not exclusively films, just in general, I used the example of films.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted that base covered.