# A powerful idiom for "low exposure"

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, metaphors

Imagine someone creates a piece of art, but nobody notices it. Like a great book, which nobody reads because nobody knows that it exists.

What are some powerful words or metaphors for this condition?

Comment: There are several, but they don't get much play.

Comment: "Overlooked masterpiece" is a fairly straightforward descriptive phrase. And a relevant pair of modifiers might be "brilliant but underappreciated."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be "ahead of one's time" springs to mind, as well as "unsung".

> "She was so far ahead of her time that her work 
>   remained unsung for centuries."

Answer (score 2):

**Hidden gem** comes to mind. The word *gem* is in itself used metaphorically:

> something prized especially for great beauty or perfection

[[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gem)] 2 : a

Cf. also [this earlier post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237652/whats-an-alternative-for-hidden-gem).

People may also occasionally use **[a diamond in the rough](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+diamond+in+the+rough)**; this phrase, which I originally suggested, appears to have a range of meanings, including "Someone who is basically good hearted but lacking social graces and respect for the law." ([source](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-diamond-in-the-rough.html)), and therefore appears less suitable.
Thanks to Oldbag for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for **"hidden gem"** - but, in my experience, *"a diamond in the rough"* is mostly used (nowadays) ironically (to describe a lovable loser) or, sarcastically (to describe a real slob). (US)

Comment: @Oldbag Thank you. I looked up a few instances, and I agree that quite often it is used as you say, or (perhaps even more) as "a gifted but socially uncouth person" etc. I will edit.