# What is a synonym for "relatively unknown"?

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to describe a place that is not often publicized in tourist guides and is not frequently visited. I currently have "visit the relatively unknown", but I am not particularly happy with the phrase because it sounds vaguely snobby to me. I am also not sure "unknown" should be qualified by degree. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I personally don't have a problem with _relatively unknown_, it is often seen in relation to the more obscure works of writers and artists, or even of artists themselves. However, if you really don't like it you could use _less well known_.

Comment: I also like "lesser-known".

Comment: "secret" is a good one too.

Comment: "lesser-known" works great for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> **[off the beaten track](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-the-beaten-track)**
> US also *‘off the beaten path’*
> in a place where few people go, far from any main roads and towns:
>
> - *The farmhouse we stayed in was completely off the beaten track.*

Cambridge Dictionary

> 10 Spots To Go Off The Beaten Path in Italy
>
> Rome, Florence, and Venice make up the Italian trifecta that we all include on our Italian travel itinerary, **but getting off the beaten path** during your trip is where you’ll experience true local flavor. From scenic hill towns and rural landscapes to seaside beaches and picturesque lakes, Italy has something to offer for every type of traveler.
> ([source](http://theeverygirl.com/10-spots-to-go-off-the-beaten-path-in-italy))

Answer (score 2):

*Come visit a **hidden gem**!*

> Hidden gems is an idiom which means something which is extremely outstanding and not many people may know about; [...]
>   — [What's an alternative for "hidden gem"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237652/whats-an-alternative-for-hidden-gem)

Answer (score 1):

***Non-[touristy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touristy)*** may fit your context:

***[Looking for unique, interesting, and non-touristy places in Indonesia](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/looking-for-unique-interesting-and-non-touristy-places-in-indonesia)***

> - I'm looking for advice on where to go. I'm specifically interested in places off the tourist trail (Bali and Lombok hold little lure), that are particularly unique, special, or hold the potential for great photographs.

(lonelyPlanet.com)

***[Non-Touristy Places in San Francisco](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/findery/non-touristy-places-in-san-francisco_b_8059296.html):***

> - San Francisco is known all over as a popular tourist destination. With visitors from around the world seeking out famous landmarks, it can be tough to see the city’s sights through the bustling crowds. ***For those seeking non-touristy places to visit in San Francisco, I have a few suggestions.***

(The Huffington Post)

***[15 amazing non-touristy places to discover each country’s national character](https://brightside.me/wonder-places/15-amazing-non-touristy-places-to-discover-each-countrys-national-character-101855/)***

> - There’s no denying that the world’s most famous cities bedazzle the tourists with great impressions and unforgettable memories! Big city lights, awe-inspiring landmarks and tourist spots open you up for a whole new world of experience... Every country, however, leaves some stories untold and some of its secrets unrevealed. ***Once you step off the well-trodden path and wave the crowded capitals good bye, you will be amazed by the country’s backstage behind the sparkling façade.***

(brightside.me)

[enter link description here](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/looking-for-unique-interesting-and-non-touristy-places-in-indonesia)

Comment: *... step off the well-trodden path ...* Thanks! You have confirmed that the idiomatic expression is indeed **off the beaten path/track**

Comment: @Mari-LouA - off the beaten track is a good but too generic suggestion, it is not tourist specific.

Comment: "Non-touristy" is very informal, and is listed in only one dictionary :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - widely used in the net though, expecially in dedicated sites for tourists.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A(1) As was implicitly stated in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I voted for "off the beaten track", but you may visit **unheralded places**.

> Definition: Not known or difficult to know;  Not acknowledged or acclaimed; unpublicized.
>
> Example: *But there are
> some instances when filmmakers would look for a little-known or remote
> place to film their scenes, for the sake of creating a more authentic
> feel for their projects. And luckily for some of these unheralded
> places, they will experience a surge of tourism as a result of these
> filming productions*.